# can "not" substitute a negative independent clause

Tags: negation

If I said, "I will dance in the production (pause and sigh) not because my mom wants me to..."

is "not" negating "because my mom wants me to" or is it serving as a substitute for the negative of "I will dance in the production"?

Answer (score 1):

In this case the "not because" is referring to what the speaker's mother wants. Their mother wants them to dance in the production, and the speaker *will* dance in the production, but they are not doing it *because* their mother would like them to. They are doing it for some other reason, which would be detailed in the rest of the sentence.

If the sentence was instead "I will not dance in the production because my mom wants me to" that would mean the speaker *will not* dance, and the reason they won't dance is that their mother would prefer they *not* do it.